# A data contract that simply takes a string

Tags: wcf

Newbie in WCF, I am to define a restful interface for taking in requests in xml. The xml can belongs to any type of schema, instead of defining a data contract describing every data member, I want to my data contract to a simple string, which basicaly says you can send me anything, ideally, it looks below,

```
[OperationContract]
void SubmitESBMessage(string data);
```

Tried to define the contract to be

```
[DataContract]
public class OnRampData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't want to tell my users to escape their xml and put into the OnRampData.

Anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take any XML as your input, then you can use `XmlElement` or `XElement` as the parameter type. WCF treats those types as "all the XML from the request body".

```
[OperationContract]
void SubmitESBMessage(XElement data);
```

Comment: Great informaiton, I will try it out. So what if the user submit a invalid XML fragment?

Comment: Invalid XML won't work (it can't be parsed as that type). If you want to accept *anything*, you can use the raw programming model, taking a `Stream` as a parameter. See more information at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx